# Error when performing Inheritance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to comprehend inheritance in typescript

```
class user {
  name: string;
  email: string;

  constructor(name: string, email: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }

  checkUserData = id => {
    console.log(
      "This user name is" +
        this.name +
        "his email address is" +
        this.email +
        "and his ID is" +
        id
    );
  };
}

class college extends user {
  id: number;

  constructor(name, email, id) {
    super(name, email);
    this.id = id;
  }

  checkUserData = () => {
    super.checkUserData(this.id);
  };
}

let newUser: user = new college("Rohit Bhatia", "iro@gmail.com", 4556);

console.log(newUser.checkUserData());
```

This is my code, Here I am getting following error

> index.ts:31:11 - error TS2340: Only public and protected methods of
>   the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.
>
> 31     super.checkUserData(this.id);
>                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> index.ts:37:13 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
>
> 37 console.log(newUser.checkUserData());
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> index.ts:10:19
>       10   checkUserData = id => {
>                            ~~
>       An argument for 'id' was not provide

*In my code, I don't see use of `private method` so why am I getting that error? Also, I know there is so much wrong in my code, Can someone help me fixing it?*

**What are my intentions?**

Inherting class user, 
creating a new property checkUserData in parent class (considering this as a common class) which takes ID as a parameter, 
Calling that class from one its child and passing id to it.

Comment: You are making `checkUserData` a function-valued property instead of a method.  They are different. Try `checkUserData(id: number) { /* impl */ }` instead of `checkUserData = id => { /* impl */ }`.

Comment: Also for your second question, don't annotate `newUser` as `user` and then try to call its `checkUserData()` method with no argument, because `user.checkUserData()` takes an argument.  You need to annotate it as `let newUser: college` or just `let newUser = new college(...)`.  Once you widen `newUser` from `college` to `user`, the compiler has no idea that it is a `college` anymore and won't let you call `college`-specific methods.

Comment: And usually SO works best with just one subject per question... "help me fix all these issues" is helpful to the asker but not much help to people coming later.  So if you have multiple issues you should probably open multiple questions.

Comment: If any of these comments helps I might flesh them out into an answer when I get to a real computer (otherwise I won't be offended if someone else decides to make a real answer before me)

Comment: I partially got what you said, can you explain it in details what you are trying to convery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like two separate questions, but I will answer them both here:

---

Here's how I'd alter your code:

```
// non-primitive types should start with a capital letter by convention
class User {
  name: string;
  email: string;

  constructor(name: string, email: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }

  // a method on the prototype, not an instance property
  checkUserData(id: number) {
    console.log(
      "This user name is" +
      this.name +
      "his email address is" +
      this.email +
      "and his ID is" +
      id
    );
  };
}


// non-primitive types should start with a capital letter by convention
class College extends User {
  id: number;

  // annotate types on function parameters
  constructor(name: string, email: string, id: number) {
    super(name, email);
    this.id = id;
  }

  // a method on the prototype, not function property
  checkUserData() {
    super.checkUserData(this.id);
  };
}

// do not widen to user type, let the compiler infer as college
let newUser = new College("Rohit Bhatia", "iro@gmail.com", 4556);

console.log(newUser.checkUserData());
```

Note: By convention, non-primitive types start with an uppercase letter, so I've changed `user` to `User` and `college` to `College`.  It's not *invalid* to have lowercase class names, but it violates expectations.  Feel free to leave them lowercase if you want.

---

Question One: "why can't I call `super`?"

Answer One: you are using function properties instead of methods.  Use methods instead.

Detail:  I have changed `checkUserData()` in both `User` and `College` to be a [prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods).  That means that they are added to `User.prototype` and `College.prototype`, and instances of `User` and `College` just inherit them via [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheriting_properties).  Now you can use `this` and [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) inside `College.prototype.checkUserData()`.  The way you defined the methods, as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this wasn't possible.  An arrow function does not have its own `this` or `super` context, and each instance of `User` and `College` would get its [own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) copy of the arrow function, so you couldn't override it via prototypical inheritance.  Arrow functions are (as it says in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) ill-suited as methods.

---

Question Two: "why does `newUser.checkUserData()` give me an error?"

Answer Two: you have declared that `newUser` is of type `User`.  Leave it unannotated, or declare it as type `College` instead.

Detail:  When you say `let newUser: User = ...` you are telling the compiler that it is a `User`, and the compiler will not try to figure out if it is a more specific type like `College`, even though you know it is one.  Since a `User` instance requires its `checkUserData()` method to take a single argument, you will get an error.  The way to fix this is to let the compiler know that `newUser` is actually a `College`.  You can do this explicitly by annotating it (`let newUser: College = ...`), or you can just leave out the annotation and let the compiler [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) that it's a `College` instance by looking at the return type of `new College(...)`.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!