# TypeScript: Cannot call super method on child class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, abstract-class, super

When I try to override a parent method and I use super inside, I get this error:

> error TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are
>   accessible via the 'super' keyword.
>
> ```
>     return super.toJson(["password", ...blacklist]);
> ```

This is an example:

```
abstract class BaseUser {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    toJson = () => {
        return Object.assign({}, this);
    }
}

class MyUser {
   ...
   toJson = (blacklist) => {
       ...
       const obj = super.toJson();
       ... 
   }
}
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: MyUser does `extend` BaseUser in you code. Even if it did, `toJson` is not a method it is a field that is a function and thus not present on the prototype (it is assigned in the constructor) and you can't call it through `super`. Make it a regular method and it should work

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but your comment says it all so I let you post it as an answer if you want to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance method call triggers Typescript compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088947/inheritance-method-call-triggers-typescript-compiler-error)

Answer (score 3):

As @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir said in the comments, you should use method instead. You can check these answers:

[Inheritance method call triggers Typescript compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088947/inheritance-method-call-triggers-typescript-compiler-error)

[Error when performing Inheritance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844357/error-when-performing-inheritance-in-typescript)